# Kernel.pp raises NoMethodError in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am using Ruby 2.6.3

Ruby ri documents pp as:

> prints arguments in pretty form.

Anyways, in a file, when I write and run the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

Kernel.pp 'hi'
pp 'hi'
```

I get NoMethodError.

But how does the following code work?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

pp 'hi'
Kernel.pp 'hi'
```

Output:

```
"hi"
"hi"
```

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gwp3.jpg)

Comment: You've had the good fortune of receiving two excellent answers.

Comment: Yup! I'm just lucky enough ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of `pp` method is by default a private method of `Kernel` module. Here's its [source](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-pp):

```
def pp(*objs)
  require 'pp'
  pp(*objs)
end
```

So as we see, it has side effect of loading `pp` file. And it seems this file redefines `pp` method, since we don't get stack too deep error from infinite recursion. This is indeed the case. In [`pp` file source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/pp.rb) we have something like this:

```
module Kernel
  # Returns a pretty printed object as a string.
  #
  # In order to use this method you must first require the PP module:
  #
  #   require 'pp'
  #
  # See the PP module for more information.
  def pretty_inspect
    PP.pp(self, ''.dup)
  end

  # prints arguments in pretty form.
  #
  # pp returns argument(s).
  def pp(*objs)
    objs.each {|obj|
      PP.pp(obj)
    }
    objs.size <= 1 ? objs.first : objs
  end
  module_function :pp
end
```

So as we see, it redefines `pp` method as public Kernel instance method. That's why explicit call of `pp` before `pp` was called properly raises an error. And that's why after you call `pp` properly, the error disappears.

Comment: I know the env ruby is reliable and I should use it. But I am on Arch Linux which has the latest stable version of Ruby. BTW, here's a screenshot:

https://imgur.com/aGO2v8x

Comment: @S.Goswami your question lacks a bit information that what you're facing is actually caused by explicit private method call attempt. Anyway, I edited my answer, I guess it now answers your question.

Comment: It looks a bit weird... When you call the `Kernel.pp` it raises NoMethodError because it's a private method. When you call `pp` directly from main Object, it prints something to STDOUT, but then when you call `Kernel.pp` it works fine, it looks like the private method `pp` of module Kernel acts like a public method!

Comment: @S.Goswami read my and Holger's answers carefully. It's all there. Long story short, first `pp` call actually redefines `pp` method and from now on it's public instead of private.

Answer (score 5):

The actual `pp` method is implemented in a module shipped with Ruby which is also called `pp`. With older Rubies, in order to use the method, you had to always run

```rb
require 'pp'
pp "foo"
```

Newer Rubies ship with a convenience method in [`Kernel#pp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Kernel.html#method-i-pp) which automatically requires the `pp` module and runs the method. After the first invocation of this method (and thus with the `require` of the module), the former method is replaced with the actually intended `pp` method.

Thus, if you first run the instance method `pp` (which is available as a private method on all Objects in Ruby which include the `Kernel` module, i.e. about all Objects), the `pp` module is loaded and the other methods (including the `Kernel.pp` class method becomes available.